# Hide specific shipping methods when coupon is applied

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

I have created a coupon code "Tiendas" for double x2 shipping price and disable free default store shipping (orders > 50€).

Also, the coupon enables free shipping but increase order value to >250€.

I have 3 shipping methods on my store:

- `flat_rate:1`
- `flat_rate:7`
- `Free_shipping`

When coupon is enabled, `flat_rate:7` and free shipping must be hidden. And `flat_rate:1` should be visible and its shipping cost x2 (4.80 € x 2= 9.60 €)

Only works if i type `flat_rate`, instead `flat_rate:1`, but hide all shipping methods instead one.

Based on *"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52912181/applied-coupons-disable-free-shipping-conditionally-in-woocommerce/52913005#52913005"* answer thread, here is my code attempt:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'coupons_removes_free_shipping', 10, 2 );
function coupons_removes_free_shipping( $rates, $package ){
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return $rates;

    $min_subtotal      = 250; // Minimal subtotal allowing free shipping

    // Get needed cart subtotals
    $subtotal_excl_tax = WC()->cart->get_subtotal();
    $subtotal_incl_tax = $subtotal_excl_tax + WC()->cart->get_subtotal_tax();
    $discount_excl_tax = WC()->cart->get_discount_total();
    $discount_incl_tax = $discount_total + WC()->cart->get_discount_tax();

    // Calculating the discounted subtotal including taxes
    $discounted_subtotal_incl_taxes = $subtotal_incl_tax - $discount_incl_tax;

    $applied_coupons   = WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons();
    if( in_array( 'tiendas',$applied_coupons ) && sizeof($applied_coupons) > 0 && $discounted_subtotal_incl_taxes < $min_subtotal ){
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){

            // Set 2x cost"
            if( $rate->method_id === 'flat_rate:1' ){
                // Set 2x of the cost
                $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $rates[$rate_key]->cost * 2;}
 
            // Disable "flat_rate:7"
            if( $rate->method_id === 'flat_rate:7'  ){
                unset($rates[$rate_key]);

 
            // Disable "Free shipping"
            if( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id  ){
                unset($rates[$rate_key]);
 
                
            }
        }
    }
    }
    return $rates;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are there, all you have to do is to compare `$rate_key` instead of `$rate->mothod_id`

You code should look like this:

```
if( in_array( 'tiendas',$applied_coupons ) && sizeof($applied_coupons) > 0 && $discounted_subtotal_incl_taxes < $min_subtotal ){
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){

            // Set 2x cost"
            if( $rate_key === 'flat_rate:1' ){
                // Set 2x of the cost
                $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $rates[$rate_key]->cost * 2;
            }

            // Disable "flat_rate:7"
            if( $rate_key === 'flat_rate:7'  ){
                unset($rates[$rate_key]);
            }


            // Disable "Free shipping"
            if( 'free_shipping' === $rate_key  ){
                unset($rates[$rate_key]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Or, a bit simplier:

```
if( in_array( 'tiendas',$applied_coupons ) && sizeof($applied_coupons) > 0 && $discounted_subtotal_incl_taxes < $min_subtotal ){
  unset($rates['flat_rate:7']);
  unset($rates['free_shipping']);

  foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
            if( $rate_key === 'flat_rate:1' ) $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $rates[$rate_key]->cost * 2;                 // Set 2x of the cost
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note1**: Correct the typo! **o** to **e**

```
//$rate->mothod_id
  $rate->method_id
```

**Note2**: For the free method

```
if( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id  ){
   unset($rates[$rate_key]);
}
```

**or**: with index:

```
if( 'free_shipping:7' === $rate_key  ){
   unset($rates[$rate_key]);
}
```