# Disable free shipping for specific coupon type in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon, shipping-method

I'm using [Disable free shipping for specific coupon codes in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63964098/11987538) answer code

I would like to target a coupon type instead of specific codes. How would I go about this? I would like to target 'smart_coupons' as the type.

Update - this is what I've come up with, although it's taking quite some time to load. It might just be my WP as I have many coupons. Any way to only call entered coupons at the checkout vs all coupons?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_free_shipping_method_based_on_coupons', 10, 2 );
function hide_free_shipping_method_based_on_coupons( $rates, $package )
{
    $coupons            = WC()->cart->get_coupons();
    $applied_coupons    = WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons(); // Applied coupons
    
    foreach($coupons as $coupon_code) {
    $coupon = new WC_Coupon( $coupon_code );
    echo $coupon->get_discount_type();
    }
    
    if($coupon->get_discount_type() === 'smart_coupon') {
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
        // Targetting "Free shipping"
        if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
            unset($rates[$rate_key]); // hide free shipping method
        }
    }
}
return $rates;
}
```

Comment: Can you specify coupon type or discount type?

Comment: Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show [what you have tried so far to solve your problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Discount Type is 'smart_coupons'

Answer (score 1):

The question is unclear what you want to achieve.
Read more about WC_Coupon [here](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Coupon.html).

Here are some pointers:

```
function check_coupon_type() {
    //Following function will show coupon discount type on checkout page
        // We need to get all coupons used.
        $coupons = WC()->cart->get_coupons();
        // Loop each of them and echo discount type.
        foreach($coupons as $coupon_code) {
            $coupon = new WC_Coupon( $coupon_code );
            echo $coupon->get_discount_type();
        }
}
//Depending on what you want to check / restrict hook to the proper action
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'check_coupon_type', 10, 0 );
```

Comment: I would like to target a coupon type instead of an array of specific codes

Comment: The example above return type of discount (percent,fixed_cart or fixed_product) . These are default coupon types of woocommerce. In foreach loop you can var_dump($coupon) to see all the data. From threre you can do conditions depending on your needs eg - if($coupon->get_discount_type() === 'percent') { do stuff }